# Should [cicd] only be used when a question includes both CI and CD explicitly?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

I came across [this question](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/13256/monorepo-manifests-image-tag-replacement-in-github-actions) about a GitHub action in a monorepo and it was tagged with [cicd](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cicd) and [continuous-integration](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/continuous-integration). Because it involves GitHub actions, it naturally involves CI but not necessarily CD.

If a question is tagged with [cicd](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cicd) but doesn't discuss CD, should it be retagged with [continuous-integration](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/continuous-integration)?

I guess this should also raise the complementary question of whether [cicd](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cicd) without CI should be retagged with [continuous-delivery](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/continuous-delivery) or [continuous-deployment](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/continuous-deployment).

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the real question is: shoudl [cicd](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cicd) be burninated as it is a meta tag encompassing the two others.

Now in term of usage, peoples are more likely to tags things with [cicd](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cicd) and I assume watcher of these 3 tags overlap at nearly 100%, so in term of user-friendlyness, I'd let it as is and don't removed tags overzealously unless they are totally unrelated.

I was on the fence about rejecting your edit, removing the [git](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/git) where the problem is specifically aroung committing within github action is kind of harming the question. Adding monorepo is debatable but does no harm, adding github-action is a great addition.

Back to [cicd](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cicd) in this case the problem is around  preparing the deployment files for kubernetes, so it is absolutely about conitnuous devivery, the fact the author didn't expose its deploy job coming later doesn't mean there's none.

So at the end of the day, I'd avoid removing this tag unless the question is neither about CI **or** CD.

Comment: I think you're looking at it the wrong way. With a question that could have so many different tags, you have to be objective about it. Git is not discussed in any way within the question; same for continuous delivery. There are other tags that fit the question far better than those anyway. Either [tag:continuous-integration] and [tag:continuous-delivery] should merge into [tag:cicd] or there should be no overlap.

Comment: This beg the question of what the tags are for in your point of view, I think we have a far different approach to them. Check your own question here on meta, retagging implies tags, that overlaps.And seriously, if "and push changed files to another branch/repo" is not about git I don't know what it is. The whole question is about keeping the file history in git when doing a push... (and the solution is to not force push).